# Map Route in RouteConfig.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 and I have following code in `RouteConfig.cs` file.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "User",
    url: "User/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

For some unknown reason the above code changes all website links (like Home, Contact Us etc) to "localhost/User/Home".

What I want to achieve:
The reason I added the first MapRoute is, when a member login to account, I want "User/" to appear just before controller name for all the pages/urls that are accessible by members only.

Comment: The first route just prefixes the "User" part to the second one. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Show some samples of the URLs that you want to used, with their correspondign set of controller / action / params, and will be able to help you achieve what you want.

Comment: Remove the `/{controller}` part from your first route.

Comment: More information about what I want to achieve is added.

Answer (score 0):

Your first route is just the same (parameters) as your second route. It will check all the routes starting with the first route you declared. The first route that matches the parameters that are give, will be used.

So in your case, if you pass a controller, action and an id, the first route will allways be used, ans you will allways get this url or link: "localhost/User/Home".

Edit:
If you want to achieve what you want, place everything from the user in a new User area and mention the aera in your route.